# Launching Ionic app using web URL

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Here is my situation:

1. User request an email of forgot password.
2. User use their Android/iPhone to open email and tap on the link inside the email
3. When the link is tapped (clicked), it'll call the Ionic app.

I spend the whole morning to research and found this [solution](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme): using a plugin of Cordova named `Custom-URL-scheme`.
I also found out a tutorial from [sysgears](http://sysgears.com/notes/launch-ionic-app-with-a-web-or-email-link/) that I need to add this code into my `app.js` file:

```
.run(['$state', '$window',
    function($state, $window) {
        $window.addEventListener('LaunchUrl', function(event) {
            // gets page name from url
            var page =/.*:[/]{2}([^?]*)[?]?(.*)/.exec(event.detail.url)[1];
            // redirects to page specified in url
            $state.go('tab.'+ page, {});
        });
    }
]);

function handleOpenURL(url) {
    setTimeout( function() {
        var event = new CustomEvent('LaunchUrl', {detail: {'url': url}});
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
    }, 0);
}
```

I've done everything, however it does not work. I tried to type my `URL_SCHEME` (http://myapp://) into the Chrome browser in Android phone but Chrome just display an error message:

> This webpage is not available. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "http://" from your sheme, href and browser

If still not working, can you precise your cordova version, and the plugin version you use. Did you install the plugin with the sheme in --variable URL_SCHEME=myapp

Also, note its "SHEME", not SHEMA

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed "http://" from the scheme, href and also browser but it still does not work. My cordova version is `6.0.0`, I used the latest plugin version `4.1.5`.  When I install the plugin, I also have `--variable URL_SCHEME=myapp`, and yes, I used `SCHEME`, not `SCHEMA`, it's my mistake when typing question.

Comment: did you try to create a test app with only this plugin (without and with IONIC)?